# How to avoid page from reloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

It is a simple chat application where users can send messages, but it is also able to send blank messages.
So I tried to avoid sending by `window.alert("Cannot send blank message");` but after one presses `ok` in the alert, the page reloads, so how to avoid that?

```
$(function () {
    var socket=io();
    $('form').submit(function () {
      if($('#m').val()!='') {
          socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
          $('#m').val('');
          return false;
      }
      else{
          window.alert("Cannot send a blank message");
          window.stop();
      }
    });

    socket.on('chat message',function (msg) {
        $('#messages').append($('<li>').text(msg));
    });
});
```

Comment: use `return false`  after window.stop(); or use `element.preventDafault()` event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of return false to stop execution of your code. Modify you code like this.

```
Example :
if(your current code)
{
 .....
}
else{
      window.alert("Cannot send a blank message");
      window.stop();
      return false;
}
```